# How many bit strings of length 17 contain at least 5 ones?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm a really confused as to how to start this question, would really appreciate any help you guys could give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many total bit strings of that length are there? There are $\binom{17}{k}$ bit strings of length $17$ with exactly $k$ ones, since choosing the positions of all the ones determines the string completely. It will be quicker to find the number of bit strings that **don't** meet your criterion, then subtract them from the total.

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^{17}$ total strings.  There are ${17 \choose  {n}}$ ways of getting a string with $n$ ones in it. What's next?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: There are $2^{17}$ bit strings of length $17$. Count those with exactly $0,1,2,3$, and $4$ ones and subtract from $2^{17}$. For example, there is just one bit string with no ones. To find the number with exactly $2$ ones, observe that there are $\binom{17}2$ ways to choose positions for the ones, and once you’ve done that, you have no more freedom of chose. Thus, there are $\binom{17}2$ $17$-bit strings with exactly $2$ ones. You can probably finish it from there pretty easily: just follow the same model.